# How do I disable or force certain ciphers to be used with IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: iis, configuration, windows-server-2012

I figured that disabling ciphers would be the same as it was for Windows Server 2008 but it seems not. I do not have any entries in the various SCHANNEL subdirectories in the registry where your typical configuration for the ciphers would be.

Is there something new in 2012 that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I use '[IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/)' a free tool to set ciphers, protocols, hashes etc. for IIS/Windows.

They have both a GUI and a command line.

I would say the locations are still the same at least as in 2008 R2.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL
```

Even under 2008 R2 all the subkeys are empty by default, which is by design - [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;245030)